# Disadvantages of coffee?

Tags: turkish-coffee

I drink coffee many time a day; you can say I'm an addict.  Not for a specific reason, I just love the taste.  My family keeps telling me to stop drinking it, but I can't.

Can anyone tell me the disadvantages of drinking coffee?

Comment: Welcome to coffee.stackexchange!  I've edited the body of your question to match your title and give it a better shot at getting answered, rather than closed.  If you don't feel it matches up with your intent, feel free to revert the edits.

Comment: Why is this tagged Turkish?

Comment: @IvanKapitonov I drink turkish coffee.

Comment: Then edit the question to ask about the disadvantages of Turkish coffee (compared to other methods?). But it doesn't strike me as much specific question about Turkish -- much better leave it a general question, and retag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only disadvantage that I see from drinking coffee is that you don't have the time to drink tea!

At the age if 68, I average 6-8 cups of coffee daily,  and have done so for the past 50 years or so. My current job,  I got bored  with retirement,  now averages 35 - 40 hours per week involving continuously standing,  bending,  stretching,  and walking an average of 10 miles a day pushing loads up to 300lbs at a time.

Oh,  the last cup if coffee is right before bed.

If your family keeps nagging you,  take away their soft drinks and cigarettes,  then let them REALLY complain.